# PostgreSQL storage need of references

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm heavily using references in a SQL layout and was wondering if that's a bad habit. As I declare a reference with `varchar(20)`, does PostgreSQL doubles the storage usage or just uses a hidden ID to link the values?

An example:

```
create table if not exists distros(
    name varchar(20),
    primary key(name)
);

create table if not exists releases(
    distro varchar(20) references distros(name),
    name varchar(20),
    primary key(distro, name)
);

create table if not exists targets(
    distro varchar(20) references distros(name),
    release varchar(20) references releases(name),
    name varchar(20), 
    primary key (distro, release, name)
);
```

Is the `distro` value stored once or three times?

Thanks

Comment: Your `targets` table should have a foreign key into `releases` composed of  *both* the `distro` and `release` columns in `targets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am affraid, that your column `distro` is not stored once or three times, but much more.
It is in each one of your tables. But on top of that you have made it as a part of primary key that in turn make it part of each index you will define for the table.

Create your tables this way. It will save you lot of space and will be faster.

```
create table if not exists distros(
    id serial,
    name varchar(20),
    primary key(id)
);

create table if not exists releases(
    id serial,
    distro_id int references distros(id),
    name varchar(20),
    primary key(id)
);

create table if not exists targets(
    id serial,
    distro_id int references distros(id),
    release_id int references releases(id),
    name varchar(20), 
    primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: In Postgres, the `id` columns should have a serial data type if you don't want to fill them in yourself.  And this structure is not necessarily faster for all uses.  For example, to select data only from the `targets` table and include the distro name in the output requires joining to the `distros` table, whereas the join would not be necessary if natural keys were used.  Also, the given structure can accommodate combinations of distros and releases in the `targets` table that don't exist in the `releases` table--possibly a data integrity error.

Comment: @rd_nielsen I have fixed the problem with id data type as you suggested. OP uses Foreign Keys, so the data integrity is enforced. And you are right sometimes it might be better to use something else than id. But most of the time it is not.

Comment: Thanks you very much I'll change the layout

Answer (score 0):

your data is repeated. Using the foreign key [constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) (a.k.a the "references") simply means that you can not have a value in the column if it doesn't exist in the referenced column.

This [tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-foreign-key/) is worth reading.

Comment: So a better approach would be to generate ID's and create a view which joins the tables together?

Comment: Yes, having only the ID's is a common design

Comment: It makes specially sense if your current keys are much larger than an integer. If they are not (i.e.: `character(5)`), it's not really necessary. It does make sense if you have `varchar(20)`, and most of the time you use more than 3 or 4 chars out of the 20.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Postgres storage layout, but I think, each record should be stored completely in a so called datapage, so that in the case of tablescans (searching without usage of indexes) no additional dereferencing is necessary. that includes also all those referencing attributes.
Additionally it will be stored at least partly in each index, from where the referenced record will be found using some kind of record id, that depends on the indexing technology you are using. The normal B(*)Trees will work in such a way.

So the answer is at least three times and in a kind of cumulating way in each index used to search for the referenced records.